# DataObject.GetDatapresent with subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, data-objects

When I call this method `DataObject.GetData(typeof(ItemType))` from an instance of a subclass of `ItemType` the method returns null... How can i get the data from the subtype?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DataObject handling doesn't deal with class hierarchies - it's a straight string 'type' derived from the full name of the data type given, so it has no context to provide it the knowledge of subclasses. I've just hit up against exactly the same problem implementing drag and drop in a treeview.

I had two options (these are possibly drag and drop-specific - if that's not your problem, it may not be a whole lot of use) - both rely on changing the source of the data object (again, if you don't have access to that, it may not be much use).

1. Create a wrapper class which takes an `ItemType` instance, and when calling `DoDragDrop`, pass that wrapper instead of the actual instance. On the other side, test for `DataObject.GetData(typeof(WrapperClass))` instead.
2. Again, where the data object is being set, set a DataObject instance yourself - eg. call

   ```
   ctl.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(typeof(ItemType).FullName, itemTypeInstance),
       DragDropEffects.Move|DragDropEffects.Copy)
   ```

   then you can just use `DataObject.GetData(typeof(ItemType))` on the other side.

Comment: Thank you, so elegant and simple :) I encountered this problem doing drag-drop operations too. It's hard to believe that there is such a big lack on doing these operation with subclasses :/